# Detect if input is 0 then show all values

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I have this function to search the database

```
app.limit = 5; // Set a default limit to ng-repeat
app.searchLimit = 0; // Set the default search page results limit to zero

app.search = function(searchKeyword, number) {
        // Check if a search keyword was provided
        if (searchKeyword) {
            // Check if the search keyword actually exists
            if (searchKeyword.length > 0) {
                app.limit = 0; // Reset the limit number while processing
                $scope.searchFilter = searchKeyword; // Set the search filter to the word provided by the user
                app.limit = number; // Set the number displayed to the number entered by the user
            } else {
                $scope.searchFilter = undefined; // Remove any keywords from filter
                app.limit = 0; // Reset search limit
            }
        } else {
            $scope.searchFilter = undefined; // Reset search limit
            app.limit = 0; // Set search limit to zero
        }
    };
```

And an input to use the search function. Every time the user press a key, the table filters

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="search"
       placeholder="search for..."
       ng-model="searchKeyword"
       ng-keyup="management.search(searchKeyword, number);">
```

Problem is when I backspace all strings and there is no input, the tables shows no data, is there any way to detect if the input is = 0 so I can use my function `management.showAll();` function

```
// Function: Show all results on page
    app.showAll = function() {
        app.limit = undefined; // Clear ng-repeat limit
        app.showMoreError = false; // Clear error message
    };
```

Comment: `if (searchKeyword == "0") {}`

Comment: tried that but didn't work, also tried >=0

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you want to show all when your input is 0 or length of input is 0?

Comment: Just change `$scope.searchFilter = undefined` to `$scope.searchFilter = ''`. 
But you don't need `searchFilter` at all, just use `searchKeyword` as the filter. 
 And if you don't manually set `searchFilter` to `undefined`, you don't need a `showAll` function.  The search would be the empty string `''` and would match everything.  It might help to look up some filter examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app ng-init="value='0'">
     <input type="text" ng-model="value" />value={{value}}<br>
     <div ng-show="value=='0'">
        Input is "0"
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for giving me the idea , this ng-show="!(management.showAll()).length" worked for me